# Native Base - The Header component shadow doesn't work

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using `native-base` to create a **React Native** app:

I'm using the `Header` Component to display `Body`, `Left` and `Right` elements. According to the [docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-def-headref), the `shadow` doesn't appear.

ScreenShot of the result :

[image]

Am I missing something simple here? Any help would be appreciated!

```
<Header style={{backgroundColor: 'white', shadowColor: 'black', shadowOpacity: 1, elevation: 4}} iosBarStyle="dark-content" androidStatusBarColor="lightgray">
 <Left>
   <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}>
      <Icon name='arrow-back' />
   </Button>
 </Left>
 <Body style={{ flex: 3 }}>
    <Title>TITLE </Title>
    <Subtitle>SUBTITLE</Subtitle>
 </Body>
 <Right></Right>
</Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `StatusBar` i assume you're testing it in on **Android**.

The Shadow Props

- shadowColor
- shadowOffset
- shadowOpacity
- shadowRadius

are only for **ios** specific platform.

Therefore you need to use [`elevation`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props#elevation) to render it on android.

Comment: Yes, i'm testing on android. we tried elevation alone but there is no shadow appeared. i start to think that problems might be based on native-base component. i seperately call the header component at different project but it doesn't appear.

Comment: It is working as expected , checkout this snack [link](https://snack.expo.io/@pritishvaidya94/native-base-login)

Comment: yes in this file it works expexted but in package.json native-base version -> ""native-base": "2.3.9" it works expected. If you upgrade "native-base": "2.8.0" its not work expected actually in some of user notify them in their github [link](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2284)